# How to authenticate the github API request when using Traefik reverse proxy

Tags: authentication, github-api, traefik

I'm starting to use Traefik and when trying to debug the service I keep getting the message:

```
time="2017-08-23T19:02:25Z" level=warning msg="Error checking new version: GET https://api.github.com/repos/containous/traefik/releases: 403 API rate limit exceeded for 94.60.8.27. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.); rate reset in 17m55.686066272s"
```

I think this rate limit is about the Github API but I can't find any documentation in Traefik on how to actually authenticate this request in order to remove the rate limit.